# Colour cell IN a sum formula

Tags: excel, vba

I know it's possible to sum by colour - but is it also possible to have a VBA script in Excel that set a colour, if the cell is in a sum range?

The purpose is to have a fast check to visual show that all numbers in a report is included in a sum range.

| Row/C | A | note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | <--- set colour, because A1 is in a sum range |
| 2 | 4 | <--- set colour, because A2 is in a sum |
| 3 | 3 | <--- set colour, because A3 is in a sum |
| 4 | 3 | <--- no colour, because A4 is not included in a sum range |
| 5 | =sum(A1:A3) = 11 |  |

Is this possible to make, and not only for the one sum range showing in A5, but for all sums in the entire sheet?

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if colouring is a possibility, but you seem to be looking for tracing precedents:

[image]